# I logg off skype but my friends still see me online

Tags: skype

After I log out of my Skype account on my computer, my friends still see me online and I have checked that all my other devices are logged out of Skype too. Why is this?

I changed my password 2 days ago but when I log on, I still get messages that my friends have sent while I was actually offline but they see me online. Help

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: windows 7 64 bit!

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you are still logged in on your web browser, also I would check your Microsoft Live Account login status as well.

Comment: There is an answer here, in the fact that some Microsoft services (Outlook, for instance) have Messenger inbuilt, which also signals the online flag in Skype, if the user has logged in it. I would recommend you to be a little more clearer and concise in your answer, making mention of these details.

Comment: Yeah I would have left a comment on his post if I could have.